# Custom method validations with has_many through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, table and reservation with a has_many through: association by another model called Collections.

The Reservation model has a name, the table model a name and units (too) and the collection model has a units_per_table

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections  
  has_many :tables, through: :collections
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :collections
end
```

the table model:

```
class Table < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :collections  
  has_many :reservations, through: :collections
end
```

and the collection model:

```
class Collection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :table
  belongs_to :reservation
end
```

I want to create a function in the Reservation Model that prevents to store on the database the following scenario: I can't make a reservation for 8 people for a table with 4 chairs

so I created a function in the Reservation model like this:

```
def reservation_units_valid
  self.collections.each do |b| 
    table = Table.find(b.table_id) 
    if b.units_per_table > table.units
      errors[:base] << "Can't make a reservation for that many units"
    end
  end
end

 def create

    @reservation = Reservation.new(params_reservation)
    respond_to do |format|  
      if @reservation.save
        format.html do
          redirect_to '/'
        end
        format.json { render json: @reservation.to_json }
        else
          render 'new'
        end
      end
    end
```

but I'm lost here, I don't know which parameter should I give to the `errors.add` since the units_per_table belongs to the Collection Model and not to the Reservation Model. Should I add the validations in the Collection Model instead?

Answer (score 0):

When you can't find a specific model attribute to add the error to, you can always add a general error to `errors[:base]`.

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord::Base
  def reservation_units_valid
    # ...
    errors[:base] << "Can't make a reservation for that many units."
    # ...
  end
end
```

#### From [Working with Validation Errors](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#working-with-validation-errors):

> You can add error messages that are related to the object's state as a whole, instead of being related to a specific attribute. You can use this method when you want to say that the object is invalid, no matter the values of its attributes. Since errors[:base] is an array, you can simply add a string to it and it will be used as an error message.

Comment: I get a ActionController::UnknownFormat

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira If you paste your controller method I might be able to troubleshoot it.

Comment: I updated with the def create function of the controller where the error occurs, it happens on the respond_to block

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira `ActionController::UnknownFormat` is raised when the controller action, in this case `create`, does not handle the request format (HTML, JSON, JS, XML).  Are you using passing `remote: true` as a parameter to `form_for`?

Comment: @TiagoOrnelasVieira Rails is expecting you to handle `format.js` in your `create` action.  Since you are only handling `format.html` and `format.json`, it's giving you the `ActionController::UnknownFormat` error.  Take a look in your log (or the output from `rails console`) and submit the form.  You should see something like `Processing by ReservationController#create as JS`.

Comment: this happens when I submit via a form html, not with ajax. I just get in the console

ActionController::UnknownFormat (ActionController::UnknownFormat):
  app/controllers/reservation_controller.rb:42:in `create'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47900/discussion-between-franksort-and-tiago-ornelas-vieira)